# PHP list and checkboxes

Tags: php

I want to make a list with checkboxes next each item. For some reason I can print the list but the checkboxes aren't showing up.

```
$note = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content );

if($note['type'] == 'list')
{
    $note_type='list';      

    print "<dl>";   
    while($note = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content ))
    {
        if($note['complete'])
            echo "<strike>";
        echo "<dt>".$note['body']."</dt>";
        if($note['complete'])
            echo "</strike>";
    }
    print "</dl>";

    print "<dl style=\"float:right\">"; 
    while($note = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content ))
    {
        echo "<dt>
        <input type='checkbox' name='complete_goal' value='".$note['note_id']."'>
        </input>
        </dt>";
    }
    print "</dl>";
}
else
{
    echo $note['body'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysql_data_seek({result set},{record#})` before your second while loop

```
EG:
mysql_data_seek($note_content, 0) 
("0" represents the first record in the array.)
```

This will reset your result to the top of the array so that you can then re-process with
`while($note = mysql_fetch_array($note_content))` or other array processing.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` moves the internal data pointer ahead. Instead of `$note = mysql_fetch_array( $note_content)` in your second `while` statement, try a `reset($note)`. This will set the internal pointer to the first data element.

Comment: That gives me an infinite loop of checkboxes.